# Postgres Pickup command tag from EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql

Is it somehow possible to pickup the command tag from a COPY command executed with EXECUTE inside a plpgsql-function?

e.g.: `execute 'copy <table>(...) from ''<file>'' delimiter '';'' csv header';`
might return "COPY 100".

How to pickup the "COPY 100"? Something like:

command_tag := execute '......'

execute '....' into command_tag;

does not work.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

...ok, got it on my own....GET DIAGNOSTICS is the key. thx!